# Identify first change in value in a dataframe and ignore subsequent changes

Tags: r

I want to use R to identify when a criteria is met for the first time and ignore subsequent changes. Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
```

Note: first response always starts with 1.

Expected output

```
f <- data.frame(response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Threshold = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the first `0`.

```
df$Threshold <- "no"
df$Threshold[match(0, df$response)] <- "yes"

df
#  response Threshold
#1        1        no
#2        1        no
#3        1        no
#4        0       yes
#5        1        no
#6        0        no
```

In case to speed it up and reduce memory consumption, but basically the same:

```
df$Threshold <- `[<-`(rep("no", nrow(df)), match(0, df$response), "yes")
#df$Threshold <- replace(rep("no", nrow(df)), match(0, df$response), "yes") #Alternative using relpace
```

---

Just for fun a Benchmark:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e6
DF <- data.frame(response = c(1, sample(0:1, n, TRUE)))

library(data.table) #For Yuriy Saraykin
library(magrittr)   #For Yuriy Saraykin

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
zx8754 = {df <- DF; df$Threshold <- "no"
  df$Threshold[ which(df$response == 0)[ 1 ] ] <- "yes"}
, "Yuriy Saraykin" = {df <- DF; setDT(df)[, Threshold := "no"] %>% 
  .[response == 0, Threshold := fifelse(cumsum(response == 0) == 1, "yes", Threshold)]}
, GKi = {df <- DF; df$Threshold <- "no"
  df$Threshold[match(0, df$response)] <- "yes"}
, GKi2 = {df <- DF
  df$Threshold <- `[<-`(rep("no", nrow(df)), match(0, df$response), "yes")}
)
#  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 zx8754           26.9ms     27ms      37.1    47.7MB    315.      2    17
#2 Yuriy Saraykin     60ms     62ms      16.1    38.3MB     64.5     2     8
#3 GKi              21.8ms   21.9ms      45.7    45.8MB    320.      3    21
#4 GKi2             13.8ms   13.8ms      72.2    30.5MB     91.5    15    19
```

In this case `GKi2` is the fastest method and uses less memory, compared to the other methods

---

Doing it per group (as requested in the comment).

```
df <- data.frame(response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
       spec = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"))
df$Threshold <- ave(df$response, df$spec, FUN=\(x)
   replace(rep("no", length(x)), match(0, x), "yes"))

df
#   response spec Threshold
#1         1    a        no
#2         1    a        no
#3         1    a        no
#4         0    a       yes
#5         1    a        no
#6         0    a        no
#7         1    b        no
#8         0    b       yes
#9         0    b        no
#10        1    b        no
#11        0    b        no
#12        0    b        no
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this by group (I can add to main question if you like). Data example:

`df <- data.frame(response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), spec = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"))`

With threshold being first 1 for each group (A and B)

Comment: Yes. See update of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, marked complete. Do you have documentation for the ave() function? I want to see what I need to do if I wanted to modify it so that it found the first no with no following it. Thanks!

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html

Comment: This code isn't working for me anymore. I'm not sure what I did. Here's the exact code from my project. I get an error:   "Error: unexpected ')' in "replace(rep("no", length(x)), match(0, x), "yes"))"

`d$threshold <- ave(d$response, d$individual, d$frequency, FUN=\(x)
                     replace(rep("no", length(x)), match(0, x), "yes"))`

Comment: Just a quick update, this works on one computer and not the other. No idea why.

Comment: Looks like, that you use on one computer an older R version which dos not understand `\(x)` use there instead `d$threshold <- ave(d$response, d$individual, d$frequency, FUN=function(x) replace(rep("no", length(x)), match(0, x), "yes"))` or update to an newer R-Version.

Answer (score 4):

Set all to "no", then find the first 0, and set that one to "yes":

```
df$Threshold <- "no"
df$Threshold[ which(df$response == 0)[ 1 ] ] <- "yes"
# df
#   response Threshold
# 1        1        no
# 2        1        no
# 3        1        no
# 4        0       yes
# 5        1        no
# 6        0        no
```

Comment: I like this but wouldn't `which(df$response != df$response[1])[1]` be more generalisable?

Comment: @SamR I am assuming they want the first 0 to be a yes, not any change.

Comment: Great, thanks! And yes, the first responses will always be 1.

Answer (score 2):

using @zx8754 advice

**data.table**

```r
df <-
  data.frame(
    response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    Threshold = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
  )

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df)[, Threshold_new := "no"] %>% 
  .[response == 0, Threshold_new := fifelse(cumsum(response == 0) == 1, "yes", Threshold_new)] %>% 
  .[]
#>    response Threshold Threshold_new
#> 1:        1        no            no
#> 2:        1        no            no
#> 3:        1        no            no
#> 4:        0       yes           yes
#> 5:        1        no            no
#> 6:        0        no            no
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>